# Core Data crashes when assigning to a class variable

Tags: core-data

I am attempting to save the value of a managed object outside of the function that creates it so I can use it elsewhere.  (For example, I'm saving a Manager entity so that when I create an Employee entity, I can point it to the saved Manager entity in the employeeManager relationship.)

My class is roughly like:

```
class Company {

  var newManager = Manager()

  func addEmployee() { 
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Manager", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let manager = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext) as! Manager      
    manager.name = name
    newManager = manager  // Crashes here EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x38)
  }
}
```

Using the debugger, I can see that the variable newManager is properly assigned to point to manager.  I've tried changing manager to be a var and also skipped manager altogether and assigning directly to newManager from NSManagedObject() but the app crashes whenever I try to assign the value to the class variable.

Any idea what this might be due to?  Should I not assign such things to class level variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning a value like that is OK. I suspect that the problem is that you declared `newManager` like this:

```
var newManager = Manager()
```

Using `Manager()` means that this creates a new instance of `Manager`. But since it's a managed object, this doesn't initialize it correctly. I'm guessing that the problem is not assigning a new value to `newManager` later, it's the fact that the old, bogus version has to be disposed of. Since it's already invalid, things go wrong in memory management.

If you want to keep this reference, you should declare `newManager` as

```
var newManager : Manager?
```

This won't immediately create an instance. It *will* mean that `newManager` is now an optional, so you'll have to make other code changes to handle that.